# How to count unique key elements in a tuple in a defaultdict (python)?

Tags: python, list, tuples, defaultdict

I have the following dictionary, keys being tuples:

```
 defaultdict(<class 'float'>, {('abc', 'xyz'): 1.0, ('abc', 'def'):
 3.0, ('abc', 'pqr'): 1.0, ('pqr', 'xyz'): 1.0, ('pqr', 'def'): 1.0})
```

How do I count up the first key element and second key element, 
so that I can get:

```
defaultdict(<class 'float'>, {'abc': 3.0, 'pqr': 3.0})
```

and

```
defaultdict(<class 'float'>, {'xyz': 2.0, 'def': 2.0, 'pqr': 1.0})
```

I am ignoring the values in the original dictionary and just counting up unique keys (first and second separately).

I want to do something like the following, but I get an error "'tuple' object has no attribute 'items'":

```
first_key_list =[j[0][0] for i in dictionary for j in i.items()]
new_dict = collections.defaultdict(float)
for i in first_key_list:
    new_dict[i] += 1
```

Comment: I don't understand your computation: you're ignoring the values? shouldn't abc => 5.0 because 1+3+1 ?

Comment: Yes I am ignoring the values and just counting how many times abc comes up as a first key element and second key element separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for i in dictionary for j in i.items()` doesn't work because outer loop yields the dictionary keys (the tuples), and `items` don't apply to `tuples`.

Anyway, it seems that you're ignoring the values of your dictionaries. Just use `collections.Counter` on the first part of the key:

```
d = {('abc', 'xyz'): 1.0, ('abc', 'def'):
 3.0, ('abc', 'pqr'): 1.0, ('pqr', 'xyz'): 1.0, ('pqr', 'def'): 1.0}

import collections

d1 = collections.Counter(k[0] for k in d)

print(d1)
```

result:

```
Counter({'abc': 3, 'pqr': 2})
```

if you want floats, I suggest that you convert to float *after* having counted to avoid floating point inaccuracy:

```
{k:float(v) for k,v in d1.items()}
```

or in one line:

```
d1 = {k:float(v) for k,v in collections.Counter(k[0] for k in d).items()}
```

to keep keys as tuples:

```
d1 = {(k,):float(v) for k,v in collections.Counter(k[0] for k in d).items()}
```

for the second part, just use `k[1]` instead.

Comment: How can I get a dictionary with float values?

Comment: Is there an easy way to convert the final dictionary keys to a tuple? e.g. defaultdict(<class 'float'>, {('abc',): 3.0, ('pqr',): 3.0})

Comment: see my edit, rather simple. I think you'll get the hang of it.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track with your approach. But I'd recommend using a `Counter` object if you want to count things.

```
from collections import Counter

c1 = Counter(k[0] for k in d.keys())
c2 = Counter(k[1] for k in d.keys())
```

Truthfully, `d.keys()` is redundant here, since iteration is over the keys by default.

---

```
c1
Counter({'abc': 3, 'pqr': 2})

c2
Counter({'def': 2, 'pqr': 1, 'xyz': 2})
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I get a dictionary though, with float values?

Comment: @ru111 if you want float counts, you'll need to do something like: `c1 = {k : float(v) for k, v in c1.items()}`

Comment: @ru111 Also, while you could convert (see my comment above), I'd recommend not doing so, because having float values for counts seem counter intuitive.